# Is this a safe way to process gestures using one of the UIGestureRecognizers?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

Wondering if the following is ok to process UIGestureRecognizer touches:

```
        if (pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
        {
            //process touches
        }
        else if (pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        {
            //do whatever after gesture recognizer finishes
        }
```

Basically, I'm wondering if `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` occurs should the `UIGestureRecognizer` still process touches, or at that point have all the touches finished? I'm getting weird values for `translationInView` so just wanted to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> Basically, I'm wondering if `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` occurs should the `UIGestureRecognizer` still process touches, or at that point have all the touches finished?

When you get `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`, yes, the gesture is done. But obviously, unless you remove the gesture recognizer from the view at that point, if the user starts a new gesture, the gesture recognition process starts over again starting at `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`.

Furthermore, you said:

> I'm getting weird values for `translationInView` so just wanted to ask here.

Your code sample suggests that you're dealing with a pinch gesture, which doesn't do `translationInView`, so I'm not sure what "weird values" you're getting. You can, though have two simultaneous gestures by setting your gesture's `delegate` and implementing `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
    pinch.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinch];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                          action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    pan.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]] && [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]])
        return YES;
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]] && [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])
        return YES;
    return NO;
}

- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGFloat scale = [gesture scale];
    NSLog(@"%s: %@: scale=%.2f", __FUNCTION__, [self stringFromGestureState:gesture.state], scale);
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view];
    NSLog(@"%s: %@: translation=%@", __FUNCTION__, [self stringFromGestureState:gesture.state], NSStringFromCGPoint(translation));
}
```

The above code works, where the `handlePan` returns the pan, and the `handlePinch` returns the pinch, and the `translationInView` of `handlePan` looks unexceptional. Perhaps you can show us how you're using a pinch gesture and getting `translationInView` and tell us what's odd in the values you're getting.